# Cross-domain JavaScript image selection

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Been scratching my head for days. What I have is a form button that calls a popup on a sub-domain. The popup includes a series of images relating to the parent. By clicking the image to use, the filename used to get written to a form field in the opener. When both pages were in one domain it worked perfectly; the move to a sub-domain as a media server means this script will no longer work.

Here's the script to call the selectimage page [Page is on SubDomain]:

```
<SCRIPT language="Javascript">


function ShowImages(xpropref, pageupdate_form, image_field)
{
var xpropref = <%=rsPropDet("PropID")%>
url='http://photostream.ourdomain.com/pagefiles/selectimage.asp?propref=' + xpropref + '&pageupdate_form=' + pageupdate_form + '&image_field=' + image_field;
window.open(url,"_blank","height=800,width=750, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=yes");
}
</SCRIPT>

<a href="javascript:ShowImages('xpropref','pageupdate','image');">
```

And the code on the opened popup [Page is on Main Domain]:

```
<SCRIPT language="Javascript">
function pick_image<%=count%>()
{
if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed)
{
window.opener.document.<%=request("pageupdate_form")%>.<%=request("image_field")%>.value ="<%=rsFSO("Name")%>"
}
window.close();
}
</SCRIPT>

<a href="javascript:pick_image<%=count%>('<%=rsFSO("Name")%>')"><image filename></a>
```

Any help would be appreciated
Glen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not read data from another window in Javascript unless the URL is exactly the same, you mention this is in another sub-domain and that it used to work "When both pages were in one domain it worked perfectly"

That is your answer, it is a security feature of Javascript.

You need to re-think what you want to do.